# Different version of Lefschetz hyperplane theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I've read several different versions of Lefschetz hyperplane theorem. The statements are all saying the isomorphism of natural maps between (co)homology groups of degree $<n$, but have minor differences in the setting, i.e. :

> - (**Version 1**) $Y$ be a projective of dimension $n$, $X$ be a very ample divisor such that $Y\backslash X$ smooth.
> - (**Version 2**) $Y$ be smooth projective of dimension $n$, $X$ be a smooth very ample divisor.
> - (**Version 3**) $Y$ be smooth projective of dimension $n$, $X$ be a smooth  ample divisor.

Obviously (1) implies (2) and (3) implies (2). I think they should be essentially the same. But I don't know how to see (2)
 implies (1) and (3)?

Comment: I don't think they are formally equivalent (I mean, except that they are all true). Version 2 is definitively weaker than version 1.

Comment: @Roland How about 2 and 3?

Comment: I don't know exactly. If there was not the smoothness assumption on $X$, they would be formally equivalent (and true), but with this assumption I can't say. Why is this important that they are equivalent ?

Comment: @Roland Just curious :)